# jQuery: show/hide dropdown Menu on button click

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I want to open a dropdown menu when I hit a button.

I've tried a lot of code, but the closest that I got is the following code:

```
<input id="hide" value="+" type="button" />

$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('#hide').click(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('rightMenu', this).stop().slideDown(500);

        }, 
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('rightMenu', this).stop().slideUp(500);          
        }
    );
```

The menu I want to show/hide is in `<div id="rightMenu">`.

Comment: what element is rightMenu? You need to specify what element. example: `$('.rightMenu',this)` would be an element with the class 'rightMenu'. Could use this for drop down: `$('select',this)`.

Comment: ... and `click` doesn't accept 2 functions. Use `slideToggle` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`$('rightMenu', this)` is the same as `$(this).find("rightMenu")`

Therefore this will be searching for elements with a tag of `rightMenu` that are nested within your `hide` input element.

This is obviously not right as you don't have any elements nested in your `input` element, and your almost certainly won't have any `rightMenu` elements as this is an invalid type.

> Menu is in div rightMenu.

Looking at your comment to this answer, your selector should actually be:

```
$("#rightMenu")
```

Furthermore `click()` cannot accept 2 arguments. Instead change this to 1 function and use `slideToggle()` to alternate between Up and Down.

Therefore your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$('#hide').click(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $("#rightMenu").stop().slideToggle(500);    
    }
);

});
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7aCFk/*

Comment: Ok i've edited but still:

   <input id="hide" value="+" type="button" /><br/>
   <div id="rightMenu">My menu</div>

   $(document).ready(function () { 
     
    $('#hide').click(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('#rightMenu', this).stop().slideDown(500);
 
        }, 
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('#rightMenu', this).stop().slideUp(500);          
        }
    );

Comment: @hobok See my edit - I didn't realise rightMenu was an ID (as you've never mentioned that :P)

Comment: @hobok I've added a live demo to my answer.. should be of some help

Comment: Thanks very nice: fast, simple, usefull solution. Why i can't find that 5 lines of code on internet when i searching jQuery dropdown menus :S

Comment: Thanks again. How should i configure that menu is closed by default and opens when i click?

Answer (score 1):

can you try with slideToggle

```
 $('#hide').click(
    function () {
    //show its submenu
    $('.rightMenu').slideToggle(500);

}
);
```

Comment: Thanks but nothing happens.